# how to save an image to my own gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to save my images to a photo album specific to my app. I can create the album properly, but I can't save the images to it. 
I have the following code

```
-(void)save {
    UIImage *imageToAddToAlbum = self.shapshot;

    [self setupPhotoAlbumNamed:customPhotoAlbumName withCompletionHandler:
     ^(ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary, ALAssetsGroup *group) {
         if (group)
         {
             [self addImage:imageToAddToAlbum toAssetsLibrary:assetsLibrary withGroup:group];
         }
     }];

}


- (void) setupPhotoAlbumNamed: (NSString*) photoAlbumName withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(ALAssetsLibrary*, ALAssetsGroup*))completion
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    __weak ALAssetsLibrary *weakAssetsLibrary = assetsLibrary;
    [assetsLibrary addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:photoAlbumName resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@ Album result: %@", self, (group.editable ? @"success" : @"already existed"));
         if (!group)
         {
             [weakAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *g, BOOL *stop) {
                 if ([[g valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:customPhotoAlbumName])
                 {
                     completion(weakAssetsLibrary, g);
                 }
             } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@ An error has occured with description: %@", self, error.localizedDescription);
                 completion(weakAssetsLibrary, nil);
             }];
         }
         else
         {
             completion(weakAssetsLibrary, group);
         }
     } failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@ An error has occured with description: %@", self, error.localizedDescription);
         completion(weakAssetsLibrary, nil);
     }];
}

- (void) addImage: (UIImage*) image toAssetsLibrary: (ALAssetsLibrary*) assetsLibrary withGroup: (ALAssetsGroup*) group
{
    [assetsLibrary writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) metadata:nil
                                    completionBlock:
     ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@ An error has occured with description: %@", self, error.localizedDescription);
         }
         else
         {
             [assetsLibrary assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
              {
                  [group addAsset:asset];
                  NSLog(@"%@ Image was succesfully added!", self);
              } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"%@ An error has occured with description: %@", self, error.localizedDescription);
              }];
         }
     }];
}
```

EDIT!!
I found the answer on this other post. Sorry. Please close this.
It properly creates the Album but I it's not properly saving the images to the album I define.

Any help? Maybe a cleaner method of doing this?

EDIT:

The post that looks like a duplicate doesn't have an answer that satisfies iOS 8.0+ . I am now asking for a way to do this using the Photo library.

Comment: FYI - The old AssetsLibrary framework was deprecated in iOS 9.0. As of iOS 8.0 you should be using the Photos framework.

Comment: Oh Ok. Can you show me a quick example?